# Integrate correctly xmonad with 3.14.0

Tags: debian, gnome3, xmonad

I recently installed Debian 8 (amd64). And I successfully installed xmonad. When I log in with it: I have several problems like screen positions, sound missing. But when I log with gnome I have no problem. I would like to have the features of gnome (mounting usb devices, sound management, screen position, lock screen ...) and still have xmonad as a window manager. Is it possible to do it. If not is there a desktop environment (KDE maybe ?) which is easy to integrate with xmonad.

I tried running `xmonad --replace` after login-in to gnome so I have sound and screen position working but there are some bugs (no cursor for example)

Thank you for your help,

If you need any extra information let me know

Comment: A bit offtop, but my experience shows that Awesome WM have much less troubles, than XMonad; plus it much easier to configure. And btw, right now I am writing from KDE with Awesome as its WM, and I have no problems you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, just for you to get started [here's my rc.lua config](http://pastebin.com/JA8HJzQP). Nothing especial — the default one with removed panel, and unneeded staff. The last line to launch `compton` you probably isn't needed *(though I recommend it — tiling a bit easier when inactive windows are transparent)*. I don't know about gnome, but to integrate with KDE all what I was needed is [to create an according .desktop file.](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/KDE_and_awesome). Plasma panel showed all the *tags/desktops* without any farther work.

Comment: I tried but gnome failed to start my session I think I may switch to KDE. It seems better

Comment: I ended up using i3 which satisfies my requirements. Thank you for telling me xmonad was not the only tiled window manager